# How to retrieve value of sharedpreference in another activity?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

Jam.java

```
editText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.userNameEditText1);
button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.enterButton1);

sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences(SHARED_NAME_STRING1, MODE_PRIVATE);
String userNameString=sharedPreferences.getString(USER_NAME_STRING1, "");

editText.setText(userNameString);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent=new Intent(Jam.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("user", string);

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putString(USER_NAME_STRING1, string);
                editor.commit();

                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

FragA.java

```
tvs.setText(getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra(Jam.USER_NAME_STRING1)+" logged in");
```

In here you can see i passed the value of shared preference using an intent,
But I want an alternative way to get the values of sharedpreference that i have created in another activity or fragment ,how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use intent for send small data to other activity like this :

```
Intent intent=new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("user", userName);
startActivity(intent);
```

You can get this intent value like this :

Activity :

```
String uName = getIntent.getStringExtra("user");
```

SharedPreferences is useful for store data at any place and access it from any place. You can also use shared preferences for this thing. But,don't mixup both things. If you want to access user name to more than one place in your app then you can use shared preferences.

Shared Preferences Example :

Store Data Using this :

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE); 
    Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("key_name1", true);           // Saving boolean - true/false
    editor.putInt("key_name2", "int value");        // Saving integer
    editor.putFloat("key_name3", "float value");    // Saving float
    editor.putLong("key_name4", "long value");      // Saving long
    editor.putString("key_name5", "string value");  // Saving string

    // Save the changes in SharedPreferences
    editor.commit(); // commit changes
```

Retrieve Data :

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE); 
pref.getBoolean("key_name1", null);         // getting boolean
    pref.getInt("key_name2", null);             // getting Integer
    pref.getFloat("key_name3", null);           // getting Float
    pref.getLong("key_name4", null);            // getting Long
    pref.getString("key_name5", null);      // getting String
```

If you want to set it to your text view then just use :

```
tvs.setText(pref.getString("key_name5", null));
```

Comment: But I don't want to use a on clicklistner and use intent to pass data,what I want is an another possible way to access that value and display it in a textview

Comment: Use shared preferences for that.

Comment: I know how to create a sharedpreference and all but don't know how to access it and display it in another activity without the help of an intent.

Answer (score 0):

first initilize sharedPreferences

```
tvs.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(USER_NAME_STRING1, ""));
```

Comment: Please add some details to your answer, make it more understandable for people. At this moment, this is a low-quality answer. Please avoid such code-only-like answers in the future.